# Can I Replace A Deleted Key In The Registry Win XP SP3?

Tags: windows-registry

I deleted the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CONTROLSET001/SERVICES/TUNMP

in order to uninstall the Miniport Adapter but found I still couldn't uninstall it.

the machine tells me it 'might be needed for bootup' or somesuch.

I was following these helpful instructions: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=2139271#r13

Now I can't even start the adapter because of the registry hole and I seem to need it for somethings, for instance my Blaze DTV.

Can I somehow find a way to complete that uninstall?

Or Can I somehow replace this Key?  This key exists in Controlset003 and 4. Could I copy that over and have it work okay?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when you delete a key from the windows registry, it's gone, there is no way to get it back. In your case, you might have success copying the similar key from one of the other control sets. If that fails, then hopefully you have a system backup, because the only other option would be a system rebuild